# What does the name Muta mean (in The Cat Returns)?

Tags: hayao-miyazaki

In Hayao Miyazaki's film The Cat Returns there is a character (a fat cat) called "Muta".

His true name is "Renaldo Moon". According to Google Muta can mean many things, including "together with" and the shedding of skin.

So is that the meaning of the word? Or what is it? If it is not the shedding of skin, why is he called Muta?

Comment: It might not mean anything. It is written in katakana officially.

Comment: "Mute" is a feminine sounding name in Japanese. -ta is usually male sounding. Might be a play on words for "Mute"

Comment: @Kai: Yes, but so are most names that they want to make "cool". They use it a lot in advertising for Japanese words that really should be in Hiragana.

Comment: Sure, but muta doesn't seem to have any common definition in Japanese, and as a name, it lacks context (unlike words in advertising, which usually have a sentence around it, or an image or something) which is why I suggest it could have no meaning.

Comment: @Kai: Ok, thanks! But perhaps someone will know definitely. We will wait and see.